# take streaming video and display it on a webpage for all to see?

Tags: javascript, html, video, video-streaming

I am working on some code that will work similar to Skype because it will stream video and audio from someones webcam and display it on the other users screens so they can communicate. I have found this code that gets gets the webcams video and audio and displays it on the users screen. The problem with it is that it will only display the video and audio from someones webcam on that persons screen and their live feed wont be accessible to other users. **Is there a way to take the webcam stream, send it to the server, where it can be posted on the webpage for both users to see and communicate?** all ideas, source code, and links explaining how to take webcam live feed from someones computer and then display it on a public webpage for all users to see and communicate would be very much appreciated.

here is the code that I have:

```
    </style>


    <script>
    navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia ||
                             navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
                             navigator.mozGetUserMedia;

    if (navigator.getUserMedia) {
       navigator.getUserMedia({ audio: true, video: { width: 1280, height: 720 } },
          function(stream) {
             var video = document.querySelector('video');
             video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
             video.onloadedmetadata = function() {
               video.play();
             };
          },
          function(err) {
             console.log("The following error occurred: " + err.name);
          }
       );
    } else {
       console.log("getUserMedia not supported");
    }

    </script>

<video></video>
```

thank you for all your help!

Comment: there are commercial services that offer that capability, but they have complex backends that can act as an rtcPeer and re-encode into a standard stream like hls, something which afaik, is not trivial or openly available.

Comment: Which is it, for both to see, or all to see? That's very different.